gtk not found, trying to build vte with coda-build
Recently I found that that there is no vte package in conda-forge. I decided to make a conda recipe to build it. But on this way I faced with a problem, that building system can not locate gtk3 inside the building environment, however it is in host section.
Meta file:
{% set name = "vte" %}
{% set version = "0.76" %}
{% set full_version = "0.76.0" %}

package:
  name: {{ name }}
  version: {{ version }}

source:
  url: https://download.gnome.org/sources/vte/{{version}}/{{ name }}-{{ full_version }}.tar.xz
  sha256: bbce30b8f504370b12d6439c07a82993e97d7e9afe2dd367817cd58ff029ffda

build:
  number: 0
  skip: True  # [win]  # Skip build for Windows if not supported
  script:
    - meson setup builddir --prefix=$PREFIX
    - ninja -C builddir
    - ninja -C builddir install

requirements:
  build:
    - {{ compiler('c') }}
    - {{ compiler('cxx') }}
    - pkg-config
    - meson
    - ninja
    - cmake
  host:
    - gtk3
    - lz4
    - gnutls
    - xorg-libxinerama
  run:
    - gtk3

test:
  commands:
    - 'test -f $PREFIX/lib/libvte-2.91.so' 
    - 'pkg-config --exists vte-2.91'
    - 'vte-2.91 --version'  available
    - 'python -c "import gi; gi.require_version(''Vte'', ''2.91''); from gi.repository import Vte"'

about:
  home: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/VTE
  license: LGPL-2.1-or-later
  license_family: LGPL
  summary: Terminal emulator widget for GTK3

I have this error:
Run-time dependency gnutls found: YES 3.7.9
Found CMake: $BUILD_PREFIX/bin/cmake (3.29.1)
Run-time dependency gtk+-3.0 found: NO (tried cmake)

meson.build:630:13: ERROR: Dependency lookup for gtk+-3.0 with method 'pkgconfig' failed: Could not generate cflags for gtk+-3.0:
Package xineramaproto was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xineramaproto.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'xineramaproto', required by 'xinerama', not found


A full log can be found at $SRC_DIR/builddir/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sergeyadmin/miniconda3/bin/conda-build", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/sergeyadmin/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 495, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/sergeyadmin/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 475, in execute
    outputs = api.build(
  File "/home/sergeyadmin/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 180, in build
    return build_tree(
  File "/home/sergeyadmin/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 3097, in build_tree
    packages_from_this = build(metadata, stats,
  File "/home/sergeyadmin/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 2209, in build
    utils.check_call_env(cmd, env=env, rewrite_stdout_env=rewrite_env,
  File "/home/sergeyadmin/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 402, in check_call_env
    return _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ('call', *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sergeyadmin/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 382, in _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, _args)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-o', 'errexit', '/home/sergeyadmin/miniconda3/conda-bld/vte_1712423580231/work/conda_build.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

